# Unexpected token " for " javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, morris.js

I'm trying to recuperate data from a json file and display it in a `morris linear chart` .
before i display data i'm trying to test if data is received in an  `alert` test.

this is the code :

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
contentType : 'application/json',
dataType: 'JSON',
url: 'json', // getchart.php
data: "",
success: function(json) {       
        $.getScript('http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js',function(){
            $.getScript('http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.0/morris.min.js',function(){

      Morris.Line({
            element: 'line-example',
            data: [for (var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
                 var obj=json[i];
                 for (var key in obj){
                     alert obj[key];}
                }
                    ],
            xkey: 'year',
            ykeys: ['value'],
            labels: ['Value']
          });
        });
    });
}

});
```

this is ajax response :

```
 [{"time":"11:01:00","val1":123,"val2":124,"val3":11,"val4":140,"val5":100},
  {"time":"11:11:00","val1":140,"val2":100,"val3":13,"val4":100,"val5":120}]
```

but i'm having " unexpected token for " in the chrome console ?

Comment: what you are trying to do in the line with `data: [for (var i=0;i<json.length;i++){` is not valid javascript. array comprehensions do not exist in javascript if that's what you want to do

Comment: i'm trying to loop inside the json array response and read data inside .. 
this is a test ..  then i want to read the first and the second value of json response.

Comment: Put that loop before the `Morris.Line(…)` call

Comment: @Bergi when I put loop before `Morris.Line(…)` it displays the line chart n times .

Comment: I meant you should put the whole loop that reads in and tests the data before the call, not that you should place the call inside the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

A way to loop over the returned array is with the native `Array#forEach`.
If you want to transform the returned array of json objects you can use `Array#map` and if you want to return a totally different type use `Array#reduce`

As an example the data can be an array of arrays like `[[val1,val2], [val1, val2]]`

### ES5 way

```
data = json.map(function(item){ return [item.val1, item.val2]; })
```

### ES6 way

```
data = json.map( item => [item.val1, item.val2] )
```

### Example Code

```
Morris.Line({
  element: 'line-example',
  data: data,
  xkey: 'year',
  ykeys: ['value'],
  labels: ['Value']
})
```

Comment: Just noting that there is no concept of "native" objects or functions in ECMAScript any more (though there are [*Native Error Types*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-native-error-types-used-in-this-standard)). *Array.prototype.forEach* is a [*built–in object*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-built-in-object).